# Sorting Distance in UITableview based on current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1

How can i sort the array based on distance from current location and show in tableview .when i use below code for sorting am not getting any proper results ,am getting the array with random distance.can any one guide me for solve this issue

```
-(void)sort_distance{
// Determine distance between current location and geofence location

[distance_array removeAllObjects];

NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
CLLocation *pinLocation;
CLLocation *userLocation;

for (int i=0; i<[self.geofences count]; i++) {

    //dict =[self.geofences objectAtIndex:i];

    CLLocationDegrees firstLat = [self.currentLatitude doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees firstLong = [self.currentLongitude doubleValue];

    CLLocationDegrees secondLat = [[[self.geofences objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees secondLong = [[[self.geofences objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue];


    pinLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]
                               initWithLatitude:secondLat
                               longitude:secondLong];

    userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]
                                initWithLatitude:firstLat
                                longitude:firstLong];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [pinLocation distanceFromLocation:userLocation]/1000;

    //current distance is NSNumber


    CLLocationDistance kilometers = distance /1000;
    // or you can also use this..

    distanceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%.1f Km", kilometers];

    NSLog(@"sa: %@", distanceString);


    [distance_array addObject:distanceString];

    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:distance] forKey:@"newdistance"];


}
NSLog(@"distance array: %@", distance_array);







// Sorting the Geofence-Location depends on distance from current location


NSSortDescriptor * sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"newdistance" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];

sortedArray = [self.geofences sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


}
```

My out put is

distance array: (
    "0.2 Km",
    "0.4 Km",
    "0.2 Km",
    "0.6 Km",
    "0.7 Km",
    "1.0 Km",
    "0.3 Km"
)

Thanks in Advance,
  Chandu.

Comment: How about adding a new key `currentDistance` or something similiar, in your `geofences` array when you populate it, and store the distance between that point and current location? Then sort the array based on the value of this key. You can easily update these values each time the user changes location. I assume you are using some mechanism to observe location changes.

Comment: sortedArrayUsingComparator will be good option in this case. try it.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer: i have tried adding new key based on your comment but  nothing was changed.

Comment: I cannot make out the relationship between `distance_array`, `dict` and `sortedArray`. Which array are you using to plot data (in `cellForRow...`)? Also, sorting is done *after* you have logged your array. Log `sortedArray` and tell what it's ordering is.

Comment: Hey @Chandu check my new answer. i hope helpfull us.,,,

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)sort_distance{
    // Determine distance between current location and geofence location

    [distance_array removeAllObjects];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    CLLocation *pinLocation;
    CLLocation *userLocation;

    for (int i=0; i<[self.geofences count]; i++) {

        //dict =[self.geofences objectAtIndex:i];

        CLLocationDegrees firstLat = [self.currentLatitude doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees firstLong = [self.currentLongitude doubleValue];

        CLLocationDegrees secondLat = [[[self.geofences objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees secondLong = [[[self.geofences objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue];


        pinLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]
                       initWithLatitude:secondLat
                       longitude:secondLong];

        userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]
                        initWithLatitude:firstLat
                        longitude:firstLong];
        CLLocationDistance distance = [pinLocation distanceFromLocation:userLocation]/1000;

        //current distance is NSNumber


        CLLocationDistance kilometers = distance /1000;
        // or you can also use this..

        distanceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%.1f km", kilometers];

        NSLog(@"sa: %@", distanceString);


        [distance_array addObject:distanceString];

        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:distance] forKey:@"newdistance"];


    }
    NSLog(@"distance array: %@", distance_array);







    // Sorting the Geofence-Location depends on distance from current location


    sortedArray = [distance_array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);

}
```

Comment: It is sorting distance correct only one time it is not updating in tableview and always first object is in frist place .places are not changing in table after reloading the table also

Comment: sortedArray = [distance_array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
[_tbl_selectcard reloadData];

Comment: and which array count in tableview ??

Comment: self.geofence array and distance label am using sortedArray

Answer (score 0):

CLLocationDistance is double type, while you are saving it as integer type. So you will loose some precision. Instead use `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:].

This will sort in ascending order, for descending order return NSOrderedAscending in place of NSOrderedDescending and vice-versa.

```
-(CLLocationDistance )distanceOfCurrentPosition:(CLLocation *)userLocation WithPosition:(NSDictionary *)postition{

CLLocationDegrees secondLat = [postition[@"lat"] doubleValue];
CLLocationDegrees secondLong = [postition[@"lon"] doubleValue];

CLLocation *pinLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]
                           initWithLatitude:secondLat
                           longitude:secondLong];

CLLocationDistance distance = [pinLocation distanceFromLocation:userLocation]/1000;
CLLocationDistance kilometers = distance /1000;
return kilometers;
}

-(void)sort_distance{
CLLocationDegrees firstLat = [self.currentLatitude doubleValue];
CLLocationDegrees firstLong = [self.currentLongitude doubleValue];

CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]
                            initWithLatitude:firstLat
                            longitude:firstLong];

[_geofences sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *position1, NSDictionary *position2) {

    CLLocationDistance distanceWithPosition1 = [self distanceOfCurrentPosition:userLocation WithPosition:position1];
    CLLocationDistance distanceWithPosition2 = [self distanceOfCurrentPosition:userLocation WithPosition:position2];

    if (distanceWithPosition1> distanceWithPosition2) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }else if(distanceWithPosition2 > distanceWithPosition1){
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }else{
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }

}];

NSLog(@"Order :%@",_geofences);
}
```

Comment: i have tried like that but i didnt sucess. Please check my updated question with responce type

Comment: You are running sort descriptor in self.geofences, whereas you are storing distance in a separate dictionary. How will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try these for sort your array

```
-(NSArray *)sortArray:(NSArray *)arrayForSort forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    return [arrayForSort sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        if([obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && [obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
            return [[obj1 objectForKey:key] compare:[obj2 objectForKey:key]];
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];
}
```

Just call it your case

self.geofences = [self sortArray:self.geofences forKey:@"newdistance"];

Have a nice day :)